# How to ask a native speaker's preferred input system (pinyin, bpmf, etc)

Tags: usage, meaning-in-context

What is an appropriate verb for asking native speakers which writing system(s) they are familiar with?

I have presented the following questions to natives before, all without issues pertaining to clarity. However, I would like to know whether any sound "off" and what instead would be a standard way to ask such an inquiry.

你**用**汉语拼音吗？

你**知道**汉语拼音吗？

你**认识**拼音吗？

你**懂**汉语拼音码？

你**看的懂**拼音码？

你**学**了哪个写作系统？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clearest way I could ask, as a native speaker, is

> 你都是用什么输入法来打字的？

输入法 refers to “input system”, and “打字” means type.

Comment: And with my questions above - do any sound funny/unnatural to you?

Comment: @MuchAppreciated25 知道、认识、懂 sound the weirdest. In English, you wouldn’t say something like “do you know the alphabet?” The others are ok, but it would be best to ask the person about the 输入法 they use.

Comment: Sorry another point of clarification: in your original answer, you utilize the 是。。。的 construction to emphasize the detail of exactly which 输入法 the listener uses -- correct?

Comment: @MuchAppreciated25 I would say it does, but I am not a language teacher, and have not looked into this in detail. It’s more like an instinctive touch-up to the sentence.